# Passing @Bindings through many nested child views is becoming a mess

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my app, I have a `StateObject` that I use as as an `EnvironmentObject`:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    @StateObject var postManager = PostManager(service: PostService())
   
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
                .environmentObject(postManager)
        }
    }
}
```

`PostManager` basically holds a list of `Post`s. I want to use this as the single-source-of-truth.

```
class PostManager: ObservableObject {
    let service: PostServiceProtocol
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    
    init(service: PostServiceProtocol) {
        self.service = service
    }
}
```

In my `MainView`, I loop through the Posts and display them:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var postManager: PostManager
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach($postManager.posts, id: \.id) { $post in
                        PostItem(post: $post)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(postManager)
    }
}
```

And here is `PostItem`:

```
struct PostItem: View {
    @Binding var post: Post
    
    var body: some View {
        // many many dozens of views, some of which I'm passing $post through,
        // and within those views, I'm passing $post as well
    }
}
```

Inside `PostItem`, I have dozens of views, and in some of those views, I also pass `$post` as a binding. In some cases, I'm passing `$post` down several nested child views.

However, I'm now no longer sure if this is the right way of passing this data down, if I want to make sure all views get updated as the `$post` data gets updated.

Is this really the "correct" way of passing data in SwiftUI? Through many nested layers of @Binding? Or should I be using another `EnvironmentObject` for individual `Post`s? If so, how would that look?

Comment: Observable objects are so inefficient that Apple created Observable. Binding is the standard for value types but there are many architecture options that could be considered. It all depends on if all these views are actually using the post and if they actually need a Binding or if they only need to read it.

Answer (score 0):

To pass a value like `Binding` into a `View` hierarchy without needing to supply it to every `View`'s `init` you can use [EnvironmentKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentkey).

By the way, your `PostService` struct should be an `EnvironmentKey` too. So that if the service is changed you can use `onChange` to refetch posts in your `PostManager` (which I assume is the model store object). Since `PostManager` is a `@StateObject`, i.e. a reference-type source of truth, it should not be init with any params because it cannot track changes to them like a `View` struct can. If you upgrade from Combine to Async/Await you can ditch the `@StateObject` and use `.task` for reference semantics (and get cancellation for free which is tough with `@StateObject`). E.g. I noticed you are trying to use `cancellables` which is already a mistake, you should be using `assign(to:)` to complete your pipeline, which auto-cancels on `deinit` of the `ObservableObject`. Objects are very error-prone in Swift, avoid whenever you can.